# xml data in setInterval not replacing information

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to create a scoreboard that refreshes its xml data with setInterval but when I use that the information shows up underneath itself over and over again instead of replacing the data that showed the first time. How would I get the information to replace itself instead of copying itself underneath over and over?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

setInterval(function() {

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2014/month_12/day_11/miniscoreboard.xml");

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("game");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
var gameStatus = x[i].getAttribute('status');
document.write(gameStatus + "<br>");
}
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited after I realized what the asker really wanted)

If you look at your data set, each game has a unique "id" attribute. Every time we check the XML document, we're going to update the HTML element with that exact game ID, or, if no such HTML element exists yet, create one.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fubfhnaj/)

```js
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

setInterval(function() {

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2014/month_12/day_11/miniscoreboard.xml");

var games = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("game");

// For every game...
for (i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
    var gameStatus = games[i].getAttribute('status');
    var gameID = games[i].getAttribute("id");
    
    // If no HTML element with that game ID exists, create one.
    if (! document.getElementById(gameID)) {
        var newGameElement = document.createElement("p");
        
        // The <p> element will contain the game status
        newGameElement.textContent = gameStatus;
        
        // And its ID will be the game ID, so we can find the <p> later on 
        newGameElement.id = gameID;
        
        // This is where we store our game statuses
        var gameStatusContainer = document.getElementById("game-status");
        
        // Add the new game element to the status container
        gameStatusContainer.appendChild(newGameElement);
    }
    // If the HTML element with that game ID already exists, update it.
    else {
        document.getElementById(gameID).textContent = gameStatus;
    }
} } );
```

```html
<div id="game-status">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i think thats what I needed. When I make the changes though it only seems to show the first game status and not any of the others, is there a way to make it show all the information as well? Sorry im really new at this and its getting tough for me to figure out...

Comment: Please explain. The code I gave you always shows the _last_ game status. Each old game status is replaced by the newest one. You say you want to "show all the information as well," but I thought you only wanted the newest information?

Comment: My scoreboard will have several games on it so I was trying to get it to show the game status for each game. Right now I have it just showing the last game in the XML file instead. I have tried to use loops to get it to show all of them but im not sure how you do that when you use ID's for each game

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I can try and get the rest of the information in the code for the scoreboar